# How to exclude an fields from populated query data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just not want to pass user id in discussion array.

Now I getting back from this route like this.

```
{
    "_id": "5f4600ab7ec81f6c20f8608d",
    "name": "2",
    "category": "2",
    "description": "2",
    "deadline": "2020-08-10",
    "discussion": [
        {
            "date": "2020-09-03T06:12:15.881Z",
            "_id": "5f5089bd265ec85b896f8491",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5f5089a2265ec85b896f848f",
                "userName": "MdJahidHasan01"
            },
            "text": "3"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-03T06:12:15.881Z",
            "_id": "5f5089ae265ec85b896f8490",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5f5089a2265ec85b896f848f",
                "userName": "MdJahidHasan01"
            },
            "text": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to get like this

```
{
    "_id": "5f4600ab7ec81f6c20f8608d",
    "name": "2",
    "category": "2",
    "description": "2",
    "deadline": "2020-08-10",
    "discussion": [
        {
            "date": "2020-09-03T06:12:15.881Z",
            "_id": "5f5089bd265ec85b896f8491",
            "user": {
                "userName": "MdJahidHasan01"
            },
            "text": "3"
        },
        {
            "date": "2020-09-03T06:12:15.881Z",
            "_id": "5f5089ae265ec85b896f8490",
            "user": {
                "userName": "MdJahidHasan01"
            },
            "text": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Select does not working here. I just not want to pass user id in discussion array just username.
As I use user id for authorization. So it is not an good idea to send user id.

**Project Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    deadline: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    discussion: [
        {
            user: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now()
            },
            text: {
                type: String,
                require: true
            }
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

**Project Details Route**

```
router.get('/:projectId',async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const project = await Project.findById(req.params.projectId)
            .populate('discussion.user', 'userName')
            .select('-discussion.user._id')
        console.log(project);
        await res.status(200).json(project);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400).json({ 'error': 'Server Error' });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this after the `.populate`:

```
delete project.discussion._id
```